# The android powered device is not responding for switching to accessory mode

Tags: android, accessory

We are trying to port the Accessory protocol from the Arduino ADK to a Freescale iMX35 board. We are using beagle board as Android powered device and the baegle board has been ported with Android 2.3.4 that supports accessory mode. 
I am using libusb-1.0 for implementing USB driver to communicate with phone on the accessory.

When the beagle board(Android powered device) is connected to the Accessory(PC/iMx35) the accessory will read the VID and PID. When the accessory is trying to switch the android powered device to accessory mode by getting protocol by sending 51, the response from the android device is that command is not supported by the Android powered device.

I am not able to proceed further. Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks and best regards,
Vinod Bhargav B S